# MySqld Output format

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand the output format that the MySql Daemon emits into the console when running. 
I was looking for documentation about the format the Daemon writes into the console for parsing it and determinate its current state, but if found noting related to this.

Example:

```
2018-09-08T19:58:11.765549Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
```

Some parts of the output are self explaining. The format seems like:
[DATE]Space[?]Space[LogLevel]Space[?]Space[Server]Space[Message]

Could somebody ether link the documentations for this format or explain the missing parts? And another question would be if the message can contain line breaks and is the date at the start of the log line culture depended or always `YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:fffZ`? (Important for Parsing).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after seeing this question I opened the documentation of `mysql` to find the relevant details using:

`man mysql`

Although I didn't get the exact answer, here is something that is quite close enough. Under the **MYSQL LOGGING**, the document states the parameters that are stored as logs.

Here it is directly from the docs:

```
   Logging occurs at the “information” level. This corresponds to the
   LOG_INFO priority for syslog on Unix/Linux syslog capability and to
   EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE for the Windows Event Log. Consult your
   system documentation for configuration of your logging capability.

   Message size is limited to 1024 bytes.

   Messages consist of the identifier MysqlClient followed by these
   values:

   ·   SYSTEM_USER

       The system user name (login name) or -- if the user is unknown.

   ·   MYSQL_USER

       The MySQL user name (specified with the --user option) or -- if the
       user is unknown.

   ·   CONNECTION_ID:

       The client connection identifier. This is the same as the
       CONNECTION_ID() function value within the session.

   ·   DB_SERVER

       The server host or -- if the host is unknown.

   ·   DB

       The default database or -- if no database has been selected.

   ·   QUERY

       The text of the logged statement.
```

Here is a sample of logs (the point to note is that each log entry takes 1 line, quite similar to output on the console). The structure too seems quite similar:

```
   Here is a sample of output generated on Linux by using --syslog. This
   output is formatted for readability; each logged message actually takes
   a single line.

       Mar  7 12:39:25 myhost MysqlClient[20824]:
         SYSTEM_USER:'oscar', MYSQL_USER:'my_oscar', CONNECTION_ID:23,
         DB_SERVER:'127.0.0.1', DB:'--', QUERY:'USE test;'
       Mar  7 12:39:28 myhost MysqlClient[20824]:
         SYSTEM_USER:'oscar', MYSQL_USER:'my_oscar', CONNECTION_ID:23,
         DB_SERVER:'127.0.0.1', DB:'test', QUERY:'SHOW TABLES;'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this ain't the MySQL Daemon nor the in the format i presented. This is the LogFile that the MySql server produces not the output that comes from the Daemon. If found this too, but unfortunately not what i was looking/asked for.

Comment: even in the docs, the exact format of console output is not mentioned, I will keep looking for it and will update the answer if find anything relevant

Comment: Thank you, i am looking for this for the whole evening now and my last resort was SO :-)